# How Do I create categories for E-commerce app?

Tags: flutter, api, design-patterns, flutter-layout

I wish to create the UI for categories section but I am confused whether building UI first will make my code unstructured so in the Future I cannot add APIs to fetch the category that the user is clicking.

[image: I wish to create categories like this using API in the future. Can anyone suggest me?]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just design your desired UI and later you will implement your APIs. In Flutter make sure that you work on UI and API together.